# HttpClient Tunnel failed, got: 502

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient

I am trying to connect a endpoint through HttpClient in my Spring boot application getting Tunnel failed, got: 502 error. I could access through postman and able to see the response.

I am using same proxy connection as in postman while starting the application.

```
java.io.IOException: Tunnel failed, got: 502
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119) ~[java.net.http:na]
```

Comment: paste the postman headers/content, and java code.

Comment: Java Code:
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET()
    .uri(URI.create("<endPoint>"))
    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + <token from Request Header>).build();
HttpResponse<String> rawResponse = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

Postman header contains only token, no additional parameters.

Comment: also postman details?

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8091/myEndPoint' \
--header 'Token: myToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "requestBody"
}'

Comment: `MediaType.here try json enum`

Comment: Tried using MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE getting same error

Comment: `newBuilder().GET()` to `POST`

Comment: I am trying to access GET method using HttpClient

Comment: then you should prove `GET` also success using postman.

Comment: I am getting response in postman.. 
Postman Details:
curl --location --request GET 'https://myEndPoint' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ABCD'
But via HttpClient I am getting error... I am using SystemProxy in Postman and the same I configured in VM arguments while starting the application

Comment: maybe you can try wireshark or fiddler to capture and compare the actual network traffic.

Comment: Resolved by using RestTemplate instead of HttpClient. HttpClient not taken the JVM proxy details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using RestTemplate instead of HttpClient. HttpClient not taken the JVM proxy details.